# Chop a string in Ruby into max length string considering new line and space characters

Tags: regex, ruby

I have this long text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum id augue id mattis. Praesent congue nisi quam, ac gravida enim viverra non. Vestibulum id interdum sapien, vitae volutpat nisi. Praesent id euismod ipsum. Vestibulum et pulvinar urna, id venenatis ante. Cras commodo eget ligula sit amet mattis. Maecenas congue turpis urna, a bibendum sem consequat nec.
```

I want to split it into (50 characters max/line):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit. Duis vestibulum id augue id mattis. Praesent
congue nisi quam, ac gravida enim viverra non. 
Vestibulum id interdum sapien, vitae volutpat nisi. 
Praesent id euismod ipsum. Vestibulum et pulvinar 
urna, id venenatis ante. Cras commodo eget ligula 
sit amet mattis. Maecenas congue turpis urna, a 
bibendum sem consequat nec.
```

I don't want to split words, so I don't want:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
 elit. Duis vestibulum id augue id mattis. Praesen
t congue nisi quam, ac gravida enim viverra non. V
estibulum id interdum sapien, vitae volutpat nisi.
 Praesent id euismod ipsum. Vestibulum et pulvinar
 urna, id venenatis ante. Cras commodo eget ligula
 sit amet mattis. Maecenas congue turpis urna, a b
ibendum sem consequat nec.
```

I tried with String#index, with String#split, etc.

No rails, thanks.

I don't understand why greediness doesn't work in my best solution:

```
str = "Lorem ipsum [etc.]"
p str
       .scan(/[^ \n]{1,50}/)
       .join("\n")
```

Yet:

```
str = "(again)and again)and again)"

p str.scan(/\(.+\)/).first
# => "(again)and again)and again)"

p str.scan(/\(.+?\)/).first
# => "(again)"

# My hope:
p str.scan(/\(.{1,15}\)/).first
# => "(again)and again)"
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Rails’ [`word_wrap`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-word_wrap) implementation might be useful.

Comment: @spickermann, I tried `text.scan(/[^ \n]{1,50}/).join("\n")` but I don't know why greediness doesn't work…

Comment: @spickermann, you can read my try and my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benchmarking best solutions below:

```
                                       user     system      total        real
Smart Reg (by Cary Swoveland):     1.531920   0.000824   1.532744 (  1.534340)
Simple Reg (by Phil)         :     0.744567   0.000159   0.744726 (  0.745223)
split_string (by Rajagopalan):     0.587626   0.000095   0.587721 (  0.588453)
With index (by Phil)         :     0.696723   0.000051   0.696774 (  0.697468)
```

The script:

```
require 'benchmark'
MAX_LEN = 70
str = "Exercitation incididunt tempor cupidatat aliquip eu sed ut dolore dolor incididunt amet deserunt culpa dolor cupidatat aliquip do adipisicing ut. Exercitation incididunt tempor cupidatat aliquip eu sed ut dolore dolor incididunt amet deserunt culpa dolor cupidatat aliquip do adipisicing ut. Exercitation incididunt tempor cupidatat aliquip eu sed ut dolore dolor incididunt amet deserunt culpa dolor cupidatat aliquip do adipisicing ut."
```

```
# split_string (by Rajagopalan)
def split_string(string, max_length)
  string
   .scan(/\b.{1,#{max_length}}\b/m)
   .join("\n")
end
# puts split_string(str, MAX_LEN)
```

```
# With index (by Phil)
def with_indexes(str, max_length)
  segs = []
  o = 0
  start_o = 0
  last_o  = nil
  while o = str.index(' ', o + 1)
    # puts "o = #{o}"
    if o - start_o > max_length
      segs << str[start_o...last_o]
      start_o = last_o + 1
    end
    last_o = o
  end
  segs << str[start_o..-1]
  segs.join("\n")
end
# puts with_indexes(str, MAX_LEN)
```

```
# Simple Reg (by Phil)
def with_simple_reg(str, max_length)
  str.scan(/(?:^| )(.{1,#{max_length}})(?:$| )/.freeze)
    .join("\n")
end
# puts with_simple_reg(str, MAX_LEN)
```

```
# Smart Reg (by Cary Swoveland)
def with_smart_reg(str, max_length)
  rgx = /
    \S         # match a non-whitespace char
    .{0,#{max_length}}    # match 49 chars
    (?<=\S)    # positive lookbehind asserts previous char is a non-whitespace
    \S         # match a non-whitepace char
    \K         # reset start of match and discard all consumed chars
    (?:\z|\s+) # match the end of the string or >= 1 whitespace chars
  /x           # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
  s = str.gsub(rgx) { |s| s.empty? ? "" : "\n" }
end
# puts with_smart_reg(str, MAX_LEN)
```

```
n = 100000
Benchmark.bm(32) do |x|
  x.report("Smart Reg (by Cary Swoveland): ") { n.times do ; with_smart_reg(str, MAX_LEN)  end }
  x.report("Simple Reg (by Phil)         : ") { n.times do ; with_simple_reg(str, MAX_LEN) end }
  x.report("split_string (by Rajagopalan): ") { n.times do ; split_string(str, MAX_LEN)    end }
  x.report("With index (by Phil)         : ") { n.times do ; with_indexes(str, MAX_LEN)    end }
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the benchmarks. I modified my regex, presumably after you did you benchmarks, as you used the original version of my regex in your testing. I suspect using my revised regex would not change the results very much. Incidentally, did you confirm that all methods are formatting the text correctly?

Comment: Hi @CarySwoveland (happy new year). Yes, all methods are formatting the text correctly, if input text is correct, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vestibulum id augue id mattis. Praesent congue nisi quam, ac gravida enim viverra non. Vestibulum id interdum sapien, vitae volutpat nisi. Praesent id euismod ipsum. Vestibulum et pulvinar urna, id venenatis ante. Cras commodo eget ligula sit amet mattis. Maecenas congue turpis urna, a bibendum sem consequat nec."

def split_string(string, max_length)
  string.scan(/\b.{1,#{max_length}}\b/m).join("\n")
end

puts split_string(text, 50)
```

Comment: Some adjustment is needed as some lines are indented by a space (and would be multiple spaces if the text contained multiple spaces).

Answer (score 0):

If `str` holds the string,

```
rgx = /
  \S         # match a non-whitespace char
  .{0,48}    # match up to 48 chars
  \S         # match a non-whitespace
  \K         # reset start of match and discard all consumed chars
  (?:\z|\s+) # match the end of the string or >= 1 whitespace chars
/x           # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
s = str.gsub(rgx) { |s| s.empty? ? "" : "\n" }
```

```
puts s
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Duis vestibulum id augue id mattis. Praesent
congue nisi quam, ac gravida enim viverra non.
Vestibulum id interdum sapien, vitae volutpat
nisi. Praesent id euismod ipsum. Vestibulum et
pulvinar urna, id venenatis ante. Cras commodo
eget ligula sit amet mattis. Maecenas congue
turpis urna, a bibendum sem consequat nec.
```

[Demo](https://rubular.com/r/W2F9jVGizguHw4)

This assumes the last line will contain at least two non-whitespace characters (e.g., a period preceded by a letter). If the last could consist of a single whitespace character replace `.{0,48}\S` with `.{0,49}(?<=\S)`.

Comment: Smart solution… Not too slow?

Comment: @PhilippePerret, I suppose whether it's fast enough would depend on the amount of text that must be processed and the performance of other solutions against which it is compared. One would have to perform benchmarks if that were a concern.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. […]"
text.scan(/(?:^| )(.{1,50})(?:$| )/)
```